# Block variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a questions about blocks in Objective-C.

For example I have this code:

```
__block int count = 0;
void (^someFunction)(void) = ^(void){
count = 4;
};
count +=2;
```

What would be the proper way to write the same piece of code so the count will become 6, not 2 ?!

Thank you!

I should probably show the actual code because my previous question was blurry.
EDIT:

```
__block CMTime lastTime = CMTimeMake(-1, 1);
    __block int count = 0;
    [_imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:stops
                                          completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime,
                                                              AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded)
         {
             NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image size:(NSSize){50.0,50.0}];
             [arrOfImages addObject:myImage];
         }

         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed)
         {
             NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Canceled");
         }
         if (arrOfImages.count > 5)
         {
             NSLog(@"here");
         }
         count++;
     }];
     int f = count+1;
```

after 10 iterations count is 0...why?!?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the name of the method you are calling;  `generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes: completionHandler:`.

**Asynchronously** means that it executes in a different thread (likely via a queue and, as @newaccount points, it may likely be re-scheduled for future execution on the current queue/thread) and the method *returns immediately*.   Thus, when you set `f=count+1;`, the completion block hasn't even been executed yet because none of the image loads in background threads have been completed.

You need to make a call from that completion block back to your code that needs to respond to the completion. i.e.

```
^() {
....
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self heyManAnImageLoadedDude];});
....
}
```

Comment: Asynchronously does not necessarily mean different thread. You can execute things asynchronously on the same thread.

Comment: @newacct `asynchronously`, regardless, means that the method is going to return immediately and, thus, you can't do anything without some means of synchronizing.  Clarification added.

Answer (score 10):

You are not executing the block (calling a block `someFunction`might be a misleading thing)

```
__block int count = 0;
void (^someBlock)(void) = ^{
    count = 4;
};
someBlock();
count +=2;
```

Comment: in the block implementation (right sight of the assignment), you dont need to declare the absence of parameters by adding void.

Comment: my only question is when global variables that I'm using inside the block are retaining its value that they got inside the block?

Answer (score 6):

Call block like this:

```
someFunction();
```

So that would be:

```
__block int count = 0;
void (^someFunction)(void) = ^(void){
    count = 4;
};
// call block
someFunction();

count +=2;
```